# Como puedo estar suscrito a los cambio de un json?

Tags: javascript, json, socket, socket.io, websocket

como esta? tengo una pregunta, tengo este json: [LINK](https://bitpay.com/api/rates/BTC/USD)

Este json, suele cambiar cada x tiempo por el moviemiento del mercado. Ahora bien mis intenciones es estar suscrito al cambio del json, pero no tengo idea como hacerlo, he leido sobre el uso de interval pero el json cambia cada seg, minute o milesegundo y por eso usar intervals no me funciona, la otra opcion seria con socket.io, pero leyendo la documentacion, no entiendo por que tengo que crear un server de socket y luego usar socketIOClient(para conectarme al server), Si yo solamente necesito consultar data.

Asi que estuve intentando hacer prueba con socketIOClient(No funciono)

```js
  const ENDPOINT = 'https://bitpay.com/api/rates/BTC/USD';
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on('connect', (data) => {
      setResponse(data);
    });
  }, []);
  console.log(response);
```

Mi pregunta es que puedo hacer en esto tipo de problema.

PD: Nunca he usado socket y ando aprendiendo a programar con js

Comment: Con socket.io no te "subscribes" directamente a un json, lo unico que haces es subscribirte a un evento en el servidor, el cual ejecutara las acciones que desees cuando este evento sea llamado por el cliente, es este el sentido de que el cliente tenga que tener un servidor socket, es porque desde el socket cliente le vas diciendo al socket servidor que se debe ejecutar cierto evento en el servidor, este a su vez puede llamar a algún evento al cual se subscribió el cliente solamente diciéndole que lo ejecute. es asi como funciona socket.io

Comment: De hecho cuando el socket cliente se conecta satisfactoriamente al servidor, este socket queda ligado con eventos del servidor, (cuando se hace socket.on connection en el servidor se ligara el socket cliente automaticamente a los eventos descritos en el servidor).

Comment: De hecho no creo que socket.io sea lo mas adecuado para ello... puesto  que tu json no cambia en base a algun servidor que tu controles o si??, existe firebase, el cual es famoso por sus bases de datos en tiempo real, pero pues... firebase solo servira si tu controlas el json (si eres tu el que controla el servidor en el que tienes el json), pero de lo contrario, los cambios de un json son insincronisables con firebase puesto que los cambios al json no los haces tu... y no se si haya manera de linkear firebase con un json de otro servicio...

Comment: Entiendo,  en este caso me tocara usar un setinterval cada 5 seg, de igual manera mucha gracias

Comment: Porque no mejor simplemente consultar cada cierto tiempo el cambio del json??, es mejor para el performance del usuario, para no tener que estar cada segundo o incluso milisegundos comprobando si el json cambio... de hecho no es recomendable hacer tantas peticiones para ver el json en tan poco tiempo...

Comment: Ojo con las consultas repetidas a un servicio o servidor, no sea que te baneen la IP, es muy común que estos servidores tengan configurado un *trigger* por número de solicitudes de un mismo origen. Lo sé porque yo mismo he implementado este tipo de comportamiento en diferentes servidores. Saludos